# Cannot acons onto an empty list

Tags: common-lisp

Anyone know whether you should be able to acons onto an empty list? I see nothing that says you can't, but on SBCL:

```
RDATA> (defparameter packages ())
RDATA> packages
NIL
RDATA> (acons "AER" (make-hash-table :test 'equal) packages)
(("AER" . #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 0 {1012B2C8B3}>))
RDATA> packages
NIL
RDATA> (push (cons "AES" (make-hash-table :test 'equal)) packages)
(("AES" . #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 0 {1013225A03}>))
RDATA> packages
(("AES" . #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 0 {1013225A03}>))
RDATA>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`acons`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_acons.htm) returns a fresh cons, it does not modify the provided association list. You can use `setf`, though:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter packages '())
PACKAGES

CL-USER> packages
NIL

CL-USER> (acons "AER" (make-hash-table :test 'equal) packages)
(("AER" . #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 0 {1002AB6493}>))

CL-USER> packages
NIL

CL-USER> (setf packages (acons "AER" (make-hash-table :test 'equal) packages))
(("AER" . #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 0 {1002ACC713}>))

CL-USER> packages
(("AER" . #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 0 {1002ACC713}>))
```

Comment: I see. Common Lisp Recipes (page 161) docs seems to suggest that acons did a push/cons. Perhaps I was reading it wrong, as it is missing the example.

Comment: I'll take a look at that, but the HyperSpec docs (linked in my answer) explicitly say that `acons` creates a _fresh_ cons, and even shows an example of applying `acons` to an empty list showing both the returned list and the still-empty input list.

Comment: Are you talking about _Common Lisp Recipes_ by Edi Weitz? On p. 159 I see footnote 23: "_If you, for example, add an entry using ACONS, then you don’t modify the old alist, but instead you create a new one; that is, a new cons cell._" Also, all uses of `acons` in that part of the book seem to be accompanied by `setf`. It does say that you can use `push` to push a new pair onto an alist, but the shortcut mentioned is on p. 159, using `setf` to modify `*a*`.